# $\cos^{-1}(\cos(8\pi/7))$ evaluation

Tags: trigonometry

I believe this to equal $6\pi/7$ using a reference angle of $\pi/7$, is this thinking correct or do the inverse of $\cos$ and $\cos$ just cancel out? It's been awhile since I've done trig and I can't recall the proper rules for this.

Comment: [You are right](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccos%5Bcos%5B8*pi%2F7%5D%5D)

Comment: What are you using for the range of $\cos^{-1}$? The standard choice is $[0,\pi]$ but others are equally valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\cos a=\cos b\iff a=2k\pi\pm b$$

and by the usual definition, the arc cosine returns the only angle in range $[0,\pi]$.

In your case,

$$2\pi-\frac{8\pi}{7}=\frac{6\pi}7.$$